# Titanium, Android, ListView with searchView in actionBar, how to?

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, titanium, searchview

I can't figure how to use a Ti.UI.Android.createSearchView, embedded in actionbar with a ListView.
My code is:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    fullscreen: false,
    title: 'Productos'
});

var search;
var searchAsChild = false;

if (Ti.Platform.name == 'android' && Ti.Platform.Android.API_LEVEL >= 11) {
    // Use action bar search view
    search = Ti.UI.Android.createSearchView({
        hintText: "Table Search"
    });

    win.activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function(e) {
        var menu = e.menu;
        var menuItem = menu.add({
            title: 'Table Search',
            actionView : search,
            icon: (Ti.Android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search ? Ti.Android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search : "my_search.png"),
            showAsAction: Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
        });
    };
}
else {
    // Use search bar
    search = Ti.UI.createSearchBar({
        hintText: "Table Search"
    });
    searchAsChild = true;
}

search.addEventListener('cancel', function(){
    search.blur();
});

var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({searchView: search, caseInsensitiveSearch: true});

var listSection = Ti.UI.createListSection();
var fruits = ['Papaya', 'Peach', 'Pear', 'Persimmon', 'Pineapple', 'Pluot', 'Pomegranate'];
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    data.push({
        properties: {title: fruits[i], searchableText: fruits[i]}
    });
}
listSection.setItems(data);

listView.sections = [listSection];

win.add(listView);

win.open();
```

and in logs it appears:

```
[ERROR] MenuProxy: (main) [6091237,6100945] View already has a parent. Can't add it as an action view
```

And on the device, appears a search icon on action bar, but if I click it, nothing happens. And appears another search icon on listView header, and when I click it a textbox appears to do the search.

If I implement the same list with TableView, it works ok!

thank you!!

Comment: Hi, 

Did you manage to fix this? I am struggling with the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

You have added the search as the searchView to the ListView. Just delete the searchView property when creating the ListView. To search the ListView, you have to use listview.searchText. It takes a String. You could add a change-listener to the searchView to set this searchText. I didn't tested this but if you wish I can provide a code snippet.

Comment: This works for me. I have TabGroup and one window has list view. I was struggling to do list view filter. This works like a charm. Thanks